# Protocol functions with Any and Associated Type

Tags: swift

```
protocol TableRow {
    func configure(with model: Any) // line a
}
protocol Row: TableRow {
    associatedtype Model
    func configure(with model: Model) // line b
    func configure(with model: String) // line z

}
extension TableRow {
    func configure(with model: Any) { 
        fatalError()
    }
}
    
struct Product { }

struct ProductCell: Row {
    typealias Model = Product // line c
    func configure(with model: Product) { } // line d
}
```

Hello, hope my question make sense. The function is `line a` and `line b` looks like same. Is it ?

Even if i delete `line c` and `line d` compiler is okay. BUT if i added `line z` compiler complain not conforming to add at `line z` function. What i am missing ? Do i have to `associatedtype String` under the associated Model ? Why ?

If different why compiler looks ok at below code

```
struct ProductCell: Row {}
```

You can test at your playground file

Comment: @matt if i delete line z and i can write without conformance `struct ProductCell: Row {}`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see now what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this code is perfectly legal (with line z commented out):

```
protocol TableRow {
    func configure(with model: Any) // line a
}
protocol Row: TableRow {
    associatedtype Model
    func configure(with model: Model) // line b
    // func configure(with model: String) // line z
}
extension TableRow {
    func configure(with model: Any) { // line c
        fatalError()
    }
}
struct Product { }
struct ProductCell: Row {
    typealias Model = Product // line c
    func configure(with model: Product) { } // line d
}
```

So what if we uncomment line z? Row is a *protocol*. That means it places demands on anyone who adopts it. So if you say

```
protocol Row: TableRow {
    associatedtype Model
    func configure(with model: Model) // line b
    func configure(with model: String) // line z
}
```

...you are demanding that an adopter of Row implement *two* `configure` methods, one which takes a type to be determined at compile time (the generic Model), the other which takes a String.

Your ProductCell claims to adopt Row, but it omits the second `configure` method, so it doesn't conform properly. To make it conform in that case, you would need to echo precisely what the protocol requires:

```
struct ProductCell: Row {
    typealias Model = Product // line c
    func configure(with model: Product) { } // line d
    func configure(with model: String) {}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? I may not be quite understanding why you are confused.

Comment: thank you "Your ProductCell omits the second one" is almost my answer. Can i think like Row inherit this function if exists `func configure(with model: Any)`  so whenever if i write like `func configure(with model: Model)` `func configure(with model: String)` `func configure(with model: Int)`  will be omited as well ?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal here? It sounds like you are trying to make rules for how `configure` can be called. What rules?

Comment: I will go on with the type erasure with these methods but my main purpose is actually understanding how when compiler thinks if there is a protocol inheritance from a super protocol ( sorry couldn't find another expression) to subprotocol. Inherits all protocol methods, okay fine. But what about if there is a function like taking a parameter `Any` and subprotocol has same function with different input type.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but it is a much simpler problem than the one you posed originally. Just set up two protocols and a struct and try it. You'll see that it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your patience master, I need to study more on protocols. After i feel more comfortable with protocol inheritance, probably i will ask a new question tomorrow.